# How to run ffmpeg, when libav-tools is installed but running ffmpeg says not installed?

Tags: 12.04, ffmpeg

I have already installed libav-tools. I purged it and reinstalled. When I run ffmpeg it says not found and suggests to install libav-tools. When I try that it says it is the newest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use a newish version of ffmpeg in 12.04 then your best bet would be to use a static version available here. http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Make sure your kernel is new enough. (should be..

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the ffmpeg package `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`, which includes all the libav libs and also libav-tools according to the [package details] info.(https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg).

Comment: Did not work. Same errors as before.

Comment: What is the output of `which ffmpeg` and `file /path/to/ffmpeg`?

Comment: I downloaded static version, and added that location to $PATH. The problem is still not solved. The static version works but it's not the ideal solution.